# How to add commands to be run before a systemd-controlled system service?

Tags: server, 16.04, services, systemd

I'm running ubuntu 16.04.

Let's say I want the system to run "mkdir /var/log/*servicename*" before starting the service (needed due to having /var/log in tmpfs).

Previously, with upstart, I edited the *conffile* /etc/init/*servicename* to add commands to it.

Now the service is being run through systemd, and the init config file for it, /lib/systemd/system/*servicename* is **not** a *conffile*, i.e. if edited it will be replaced on a package update.

What is the recommended way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I found but don't really like:

- Copy the package's service file to a new name: `cp /lib/systemd/system/$servicename.service /lib/systemd/system/$servicename-my.service`.
- Edit the new service file: add `ExecStartPre=...` next to the `ExecStart`: `sed -i "s_^ExecStart=_ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/$servicename\nExecStart=_" /lib/systemd/system/$servicename-my.service`
- Disable the old service, enable the new one: `systemctl stop $servicename; systemctl disable $servicename; systemctl enable $servicename-my; systemctl start $servicename-my`.

The main reason I don't like this solution is needing a file outside of `/etc`, which would be considered “cruft” by the corresponding tools.

Also, not extensively tested.

Edit1:

Correction: by documentation it should be possible to put the modified service file in `/etc/systemd/system/` without renaming it. Will test later.

Another tangentially related problem: `PermissionsStartOnly=yes` might not work correctly.